# Read class objects from file c++ (Private member variables)

Tags: c++, class, filestream

I am learning how to work with objects but am stuck the closest answer is could find was [Read class objects from file c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532631/read-class-objects-from-file-c#). 
In this question:

How would you go about the same task if your member variables were declared as private?

Comment: How do you set those variables in the first place? Maybe there is a constructor that sets them, so you can use that. Or the class can (de)serialize itself or make the deserializer `friend` of said class.

Comment: @Quimby for the purpose of the exercise only one of the three member functions was allowed to have a mutator member function. deserializer is a new term to me. I have overloaded the >> operator.

Comment: The code to read and write the object will have to be a member function or friend so that it can access private members.

Comment: serialization means converting an object to a raw string (suitable for files) and back. The << and >> operators are a good place to do serialization. Those will not be declared private, and will generally be declared so they can see the private data. You can find a lot of good info on how to implement them.

Comment: @Kenny thank you, i will do some research on it

Comment: @KennyOstrom _" converting an object to a raw string "_: not necessarily, it could be some binary format as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

Content of person.txt

```
John California 3683893

Stalin Russia 489895
```

Sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class person
{
private:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address;
    unsigned int _phone;
public:
    person(const std::string& name, const std::string& address, unsigned int phone)
        :_name(name),_address(address),_phone(phone)
    {}
    std::string getName() const { return _name; }
    std::string getAddress() const { return _address; }
    unsigned int getPhone() { return _phone; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<person> persons;
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    unsigned int phone;
    std::ifstream fs;
    fs.open("person.txt");
    if (fs.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(fs, name, ' ') && std::getline(fs, address, ' ') &&
            (fs >> phone))
        {
            persons.push_back(person(name,address,phone));
        }
    }

    for (auto p : persons) {
        std::cout << p.getName() << " " << p.getAddress() << " " << p.getPhone() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```